# How to find the "Local Identifier" to execute AFM function using gooddata-js

Tags: gooddata

I'm using gooddata-js in my project and I'm trying to use the function execution.executeAfm, but appears error about **"Local identifier no found in AFM"**.

I followed the [documentation](https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/4.1.1/result_specification.html) about AFM and Result Specification, but I don't know where I find the "**Local identifier**" to put into itemIdentifiers. I tried put **['measureGroup']** but didn't work!

```
execution: {
                afm: {
                    measures: [
                        // Type: IMeasure
                        {
                            localIdentifier: '740953a40a01490c8aaeba66a21cac53',
                            // Type: MeasureDefinition
                            definition: {
                                measure: {
                                    // Type: ObjQualifier
                                    item: {
                                        uri: '/gdc/md/PROJECT_ID/obj/245828'   
                                    },
                                    filters: [
                                        // Type: IAbsoluteDateFilter
                                        {
                                            relativeDateFilter: {
                                                dataSet: {
                                                    uri: '/gdc/md/PROJECT_ID/obj/3603'
                                                },
                                                from : 0,
                                                granularity : 'GDC.time.month',
                                                to : 0
                                            }
                                        },
                                    ],
                                    computeRatio: false
                                }
                            },            
                        }
                    ]
                },
                resultSpec:
                {
                    dimensions: [
                        {
                            itemIdentifiers: ['gdc.visualization.table']
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

I expect result of AFM function but show the error below!

```
error: {errorClass: "com.gooddata.webapp.service.executeafm.exception.LocalIdentifierNotFoundException",…}
component: "Webapp"
errorClass: "com.gooddata.webapp.service.executeafm.exception.LocalIdentifierNotFoundException"
errorCode: "gdc111"
errorId: "fe33be5e-cf0f-4195-b8eb-f28acafd8890"
message: "Local identifier=%s of type=%s not found in AFM."
parameters: ["gdc.visualization.table", "AttributeItem"]
0: "gdc.visualization.table"
1: "AttributeItem"
trace: ""
```

Comment: Have you checked https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/4.1.1/about_gooddataui.html? 
You can find section "Get resource identifiers" there. Also you should check you project ID as it is not updated within your code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a documentation of `resultSpec` available here:

https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/result_specification.html

From your code snippet, I can only guess that a valid `resultSpec` could look something like this:

```
{
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "itemIdentifiers": [
        "measureGroup"
      ]
    },
    {
      "itemIdentifiers": []
    }
  ],
  "sorts": []
}
```